# Is an empty 'while' loop bad practice?

Tags: design, programming-practices, clean-code

Consider the following:

```java
public boolean maybeUpdateTime() {
    if (this.timeReference.isAfter(lastInterval.getBeginning()) {
        this.timeReference = lastInterval.getEnd();
        lastInterval = intervalIterator.next();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void updateState() {

    // do some stuff before

    while (maybeUpdateTime());

    // do more stuff afeter

}
```

Which roughly translates to: *while it needs to be updated - update it*.

**Considering that `maybeUpdateTime` is a function/method that can be called independently, would it still be considered a bad practice to write such an empty while?**

Otherwise I would have to create two functions, `isTimeAfterInterval` and `updateTime`, and call both every time.

<sub>I used this time and interval-based example just to illustrate, but the specifics don't matter to my question.</sub>

---

Note that `maybeUpdateTime` is a "public" function that can be called independently of `updateState` and not always inside a loop until it returns false like there.

Therefore, it is important to wrap it inside a function of its own. This code is an example and thus I kept it simple, but it could be a much bigger computation.

Comment: Consider renaming the function to something like `processNextInterval()`. Then it is easy to guess `while(processNextInterval()) {}` processes intervals as long as there are still some intervals to process

Comment: Nit: "getBeggining" is misspelled, should be "getBeginning" (yes I am that guy in PR reviews :p)

Comment: I don't see why you think it's a busy wait.. This example I actually took from a class that makes some business specific analysis over two calendars. It iterates over two lists of events, keeping the second in sync with the first, time wise, using a similar method of `maybeUpdateTime`.

Comment: I would say it is bad practice to give a function a name like "maybeUpdateTime" which gives some indication of what it might do, but no indication of what it will actually do. If no clear and simple name presents itself, it should probably be two functions.

Comment: @chepner isn't that exaclty what `List::add` method does? for instance

Comment: @LucasNoetzold It's not an idiom I particularly agree with (I assume you mean something like `foo.add(1).add(2)` to chain operations together), but it expresses a reasonable idea, though conflating the idea of *building* a list with the list itself. (Something like `foo.extend(Builder().add(1).add(2))`, assuming a class for building a sequence of items and `List` method to consume such a builder, would be "purer".) You wouldn't be chaining multiple calls of `maybeUpdateTime` together.

Comment: @chepner you said: [...] _write functions that have a side effect or return a value_ [...]. That is what many methods, like `java.util.List::add` do. This rule of thumb is valid for such cases? What I mean is: I'm returning a flag that says if the side effects were successfully executed, seems like a ok-ish way to go...

Comment: `List::add` appears to do something even dumber, in that it may never return `false`, raising an exception instead. In that case, it may as well just have `void` as its return value, and if it returns, you can assume it succeeded. It's debatable whether it's the job of `add` to inform you if adding an element "failed" simply because it was already in the list.

Comment: Empty Loops are one of the Four Horsemen of the Terrible Readability. Your tomorrow you will want to punch your face if this eventually bugs out, and you have to spend days trying to find out _what the carrots this thing is doing_. Debbuging this would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**From a code-review perspective - the intuitive process**

The function `maybeUpdateTime` does not seem to be problematic. However, it definitely needs a better name, one that conveys information to a programmer succinctly.

The while loop inside the `updateState` function may trigger a false-alarm for a programmer who is reading the code. That is, it makes the reader feel scary, and compels the reader to fetch more information to assure that it is not a bug.

When a programmer reads a `while` loop and tries to understand what it does, there are several pieces of information that the programmer needs to grasp (or guess):

- Is this loop going to execute at least once?

  - Why does this question matter? If the loop isn't going to execute at all, I'm not too concerned about the correctness or applicability of the code inside the loop.
- Is it going to execute a fixed number of times?

  - If the loop count is determined beforehand, I can glean more information by finding out where that loop count is derived from.
  - If there is no pre-determined loop count, I will need to find out the dynamic conditions - what is the loop termination condition?
- If the loop termination condition is computed in another function,

  - Am I able to guess what that condition is, just by seeing the other function's name?
  - If the other function's name didn't provide adequate information (about what that loop-termination condition is), I will have to go to that function and read about it.

Altogether, these thought processes increased the **cognitive load** of the person reading the code (especially the `while` loop). If one or more issues are fixed, the cognitive load will decrease, and the `while` loop will become less scary to the other programmer.

---

**From a code-review perspective - objections that may be raised**

*Note: this section dissects into the code example provided by OP. As OP explains, such detail is **not** the main focus of this question.*

```java
public boolean maybeUpdateTime() 
{
    if (this.timeReference.isAfter(lastInterval.getBeggining()) 
    {
        this.timeReference = lastInterval.getEnd();   // mutation
        lastInterval = intervalIterator.next();   // mutation
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In the code sample above, changes are made to **two** instance fields (of the `this` object). The function's name will need to communicate either the **how** or the **why** these field changes are made.

But how do we explain the **why**?

We can only explain in a manner that makes sense to fellow humans. For this reason, we (humans) create idioms and analogies, drawing from experience from our everyday, non-software-related lives.

We also try to separate a complex process into orthogonal, composable concerns.

It should be obvious that the code sample above is taken from a class that has certain iterator-like behavior. It is also obvious that the class has other responsibilities as well.

Thus, the first change we'd make is to isolate the iterator-like behavior - to make it an iterator that is extensible, without bundling with the additional responsibility. This is called the **Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)**.

The sample code may have more than one use cases. Some examples are:

- To iterate through the entire collection, one at a time, and perform a bit of work on each item (via the extensibility of an iterator)
- To search for something (i.e. to iterate through the collection until a condition is met), without modifying the collection.
- To execute an algorithm that examines the inter-relationship between adjacent items in the collection, e.g. to find consecutive items that represent time ranges that touch or overlap.

In each of the use case, it would help if the code is refactored (restructured) so that the **what is being computed** is made obvious, and **separate** from the act of iterating through.

---

**From a coding style perspective**

Given OP's desire to focus on the tension between:

- There is already a public function; its name is NOT going to be changed;
- There is another function that calls that public function; however, the way it is called may look scary to a fellow programmer.

In this case, the advise is to **wrap** that function so that the **wrapper**'s name conveys the missing context.

Illustrated solution:

```java
// Function name is part of public API
// Function name cannot be changed
// Function name is meaningful when seen from the API's context
// Suggestion to change this function name cannot be fulfilled
public boolean somePublicFunction()
{
    ...
}

// Because this is a thin wrapper, 
// you can change its name to give more context.
private boolean advanceIteratorOnce()
{
    somePublicFunction();
}

// If it is necessary to provide more context to the fellow programmer
// reading your code, consider making it obvious what is the stopping 
// condition for the while loop.
private void keepDoingUntilSomethingHappens()
{
    while (advanceIteratorOnce());
}

public void doMultipleThings() 
{
    // do some stuff before

    // You may use option 1, option 2, or both.
    // What is important is that the fellow programmer will not feel scared
    // because the important information about the loop has been made obvious.
    keepDoingUntilSomethingHappens();

    // do more stuff afeter
}
```

Comment: I’d point out that there may well be a language construct that makes the code better, ie a repeat/until or do/while loop, which given that nothing happens inside the loop is easier to translate from code to intent even without comments, with comments, it’s almost idiomatic.

Comment: Now we just need 16 more votes

Answer (score 43):

You wrote

> Which roughly translates to: while it needs to be updated - update it.

So alone the fact that you feel you need to explain the code to us shows you already have understood that the code is not self-explanatory enough.

So why don't you write your code exactly with those words above, so it **does not require any "translation"**? This is how it could look like:

```
     while(timeNeedsToBeUpdated())  {
         updateTime();
     }
```

I am sure you can split up `maybeUpdateTime` into those two new functions `timeNeedsToBeUpdated` and `updateTime` by yourself. You can keep `maybeUpdateTime` in your code, if required at different places:

```
 public boolean maybeUpdateTime() {
     if (timeNeedsToBeUpdated()) {
        updateTime();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Of course, there are cases where this splitting into two methods is not easily possible, like mentioned in the comments, and for those cases, an empty block with a code comment, like shown in [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/419482), is surely the better alternative.

Comment: I would move Doc's little code fragment into it's own method with a good name, perhaps `bringTimeCompletelyUpToDate()`.

Have to admit, this makes you wonder why the original `maybeUpdateTime()` doesn't _already have the while loop built in_.  It makes little sense (to me) to bring the time slightly up to date.   But may be details I don't understand.

Comment: @user949300 My example fails in this perspective, for it gives the idea that it would not make sense to advance just once, without bringing it up completely to date. Consider, instead of time related stuff, a product inventory counter: you could ask the 'responsible' object to bring it all up to date, if you just want to see the numbers, or count it one by one whilst making some other validations, or side effects, for while it still have things to count (now that I think about, it's an iterator).

Comment: What if splitting up `maybeUpdateTime` in this way makes a race condition possible, that would not be possible if a single function were responsible for both actions? (It doesn't in the exact example given in the question, but the question also specifies that this was just example code and the question was about this pattern generally.)

Comment: @DanielWagner: I would prefer sticking to the question and not inventing new hypothetical scenarios. But if you can construct a realistic piece of code where a potential  race condition forbids a simple "extract function" refactoring, feel free to ask a new question (let me add I have no idea how to construct such a scenario).

Comment: @DocBrown (I don't know what language this is, so forgive me if I get function names, etc. wrong. Hopefully the idea is visible anyway.) A simple example would be `public boolean maybeUpdateTime() { grabMutex(); retVal = sharedBoolean; if(sharedBoolean) { sharedInt += 1; } releaseMutex(); return retVal; }`. Splitting this into two functions -- one which checks the `sharedBoolean` inside the lock, and one which updates `sharedInt` inside the lock -- might allow `sharedBoolean` to shift to `False` in between the calls.

Comment: @DanielWagner is right, this two-step approach is dangerous because it invites race conditions.

Comment: @Adam: this "two step approach" is not dangerous *in general* for the asked question. It may not be a valid refactoring for what Daniel had in mind, but that is a different question.

Comment: When classes are written specifically for a multithreading environment, public methods are usually coded so that they might provide some kind of guaranteed correctness, whereas private methods shall be named so that it communicates to the fellow programmer if any of those assumptions are broken. Methods that have a lower guarantee (i.e. requiring more care on the user's shoulder for correct outcome) might be marked "_unsafe", "_with_lock", etc, to indicate what preconditions / postconditions / caveats that the caller needs to be aware of. Correctness first, readability second, deduplication 3

Comment: The first snippet doesn't match the goals. You don't need repeated updates, you need _waiting_ (i.e. repeated idling) and afterwards update once.

Comment: @Flater: this may be correct - or not,  hard to say without more context. However, I did not question the OPs code; you may consider write a comment to their question, not to mine.

Comment: @DocBrown it is dangerous *in general* because it cannot be made thread safe in a sane way. Thread safety is a must these days. OP's small print says that this is just example code, so they're asking for general advice. *In general* the safe way to go is to try an operation and see if it fails, not to check if it's necessary then do it.

Comment: You can also -- and I have done so many times -- simply choose a name which correctly reflects what the function does, like `checkAndUpdIfNeeded()`. Contrary to the opinion of other people here, I like specifically the combination of side effect and return code. It is a common pattern (`while(scanf("%d", &i) == 1)`,  `while(is >> word)`) enabling us to write elegant and concise code.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica *// I like specifically the combination of side effect and return code //* is a tradition from C and then C++, where the earliest hand-written character string processing routines had to use high-level constructs as if they were GOTOs. That kind of terseness is no longer favored in all other languages. Most people, including C and C++ programmers, agree it's hard to read. However, it is still widely recognized that a well-designed API (in any language) may include functions that do multiple things if it makes sense. Whether it makes sense depends on the actual details.

Answer (score 26):

Just replace the semicolon by an empty block with a comment so that the next person knows it is intentional:

```
while (maybeUpdateTime()) {
    // do nothing, wait until resolves as false
}
```

Of course some explanation in the problem domain would be better, but don't see enough to make sense of it.

Comment: I don't see this as an improvement at all. 1. Why add a body just to add a comment inside? Surely adding the comment on the same line or before the `while` is equivalent without changing the syntax at all. 2. That's easier to solve by making the code self-documenting (rename the function). 3. Not being sufficiently clear is a *smaller* problem over the busy-wait scenario. In general, you'd want to be *notified* when to update, not just wait and poll. Might not always be an option but adding comments is not the path forward here anyway.

Comment: Elaborate though. `// loop until queue is caught up to current time`

Comment: @VLAZ The semicolon is easy to miss, and the explicit empty body makes it less likely that someone mis-reads the code and thinks that the next statement is actually the loop body. Or, since you rarely use semicolons with `while`, someone could think it's a typo and erroneously delete the semicolon. Using empty braces to mark a loop as intentionally empty is a common thing seen in coding standards documents.  Placement of the *comment* is mostly a matter of preference.

Comment: I think the loop here is a bad example because everyone focuses on the busy wait, if the algorithm really loops naturally and there's no better loop construct and the while loop has only a condition and no body, than make it clear to the reader that the code is complete. don't just place a semicolon, because it is shorter.

Comment: @VLAZ some coding guidelines require braces for any dependent statement (in a loop, after `if`). It is somewhat pedestrian, but that 's sometimes not bad. Remember the [Apple bug](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/curly-braces/)? Even if this article argues that braces wouldn't have saved the day, I think in many instances it would.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica an opinion based thing like coding style is *the least* of the problems here. I'd expect critiques of the style to show up on [codereview.se] as they are more appropriate there. On this site, I expect a more thorough examination of the actual operation.

Comment: @True, which is why it is good that both of us discuss style only in comments ;-). (At second thought the question is a design/style hybrid though. The OP is wondering whether "an empty loop is bad practice"; a braced body with a comment is not-quite-as-empty, I'd venture.)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I'd cosider an empty body to still be an empty loop. Whether you write `while(someCondition());` or `while(someCondition) {}` the body is empty both times. Making it more explicit or not doesn't really change the content.

Comment: @VLAZ: I prefer `do {} while(whatever);`, written on one line, as an idiom to express the concept "repeat this operation until it returns false".

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Using a style that regards braces as optional, but aligns open braces with close braces, the presence of a pair of indented `goto` statements not preceded by an open brace would stand out as a visual anomaly more so than the erroneous version with braces added.

Comment: @supercat Allman style. Braces clearly aligned, cut/paste trivial. Only people without real things to do fret about indentation but if I had to choose one it'd be that.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: When using that style, the structure of a program can generally be gleaned, and most anomalies detected, without having to look at anything beyond the level of indent and the first seven characters after it.  If a line starts with "if`", either the next line should start with { at the same indent level, something other than { indented one level, or else succeeding lines should be indented to a deeper level (continuations of the "if" condition) until there's either a { at the same level as the "if", or a single line that's indented one level from the "if".

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: There are a few other patterns, such as a sequence of "if" statements at the same indent level, with the entire sequence being preceded and followed by a blank line; in such a sequence, all "if" statements should put the controlled statements on the same line as the "if" (e.g. `if(x > 20) x=20;`). but the presence of two consecutive lines indented one level after an "if" statement, or an "if" which isn't followed by an indented line, suggest something isn't right.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes, the only work to be done is already done in the loop-condition, and if that doesn't feel forced, that is fine.
No need to break some perfectly fine abstraction.

As an example:

```cpp
while (std::getline(std::cin, answer) && !validate_answer(answer));
```

That works.
Still, there is something seriously wrong with the above line.
Specifically, it looks like it is only the head of the loop without the body (the semicolon is easy enough to overlook), or conversely that someone indiscriminately sprinkled around some semicolons and thus supplanted the true body of the loop. It feels unnatural, and always having to re-verify the absence of fire under the smoke gets tiresome.

To make it obvious that such didn't happen, make a true body that looks like intended. While [Python has `pass`](//www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_pass_statement.htm) for that task, a simple comment or a proper code-block is enough:

```cpp
while (std::getline(std::cin, answer) && !validate_answer(answer))
    /**/;

while (std::getline(std::cin, answer) && !validate_answer(answer)) {
}
```

Remember that while your code must be acted upon by a machine, humans are very much also the target audience.

Comment: One could simply argue that std::getline is poorly designed, which I agree with. It is irrelevant that it is a part of the standard C++ library, which automatically makes it popular. Popular != perfectly fine abstraction.

Comment: @freakish Ok, I'll bite. How should it look? And remember to stay efficient. Anyway, there are others if you don't like `std::getline`, it doesn't depend on this one function.

Comment: I would prefer to see something like `loop { std::getline(std::cin, answer); if (validate_answer(answer)) break; }` or using a do-while loop. Effectful functions in conditionals are difficult to reason about. (You probably want to do something besides just break if `std::getline` fails anyway.)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro You know that doesn't have the same semantics? Specifically, it doesn't check for input error, like end of input.

Comment: @Deduplicator I do, as I mentioned you shouldn't be just breaking on that anyway since that mixes up an IO error with a valid answer, which seems bad. To replicate that code's behavior you could write `int err = getline(cin, answer); if (err) break; if (!validate_answer(answer)) break;` and there are a variety of ways to compress that depending on requirements. But you should probably do something about `err` in the first `break` and the original version makes it difficult to handle the error.

Comment: Also the data dependency from one condition to the second is really sketchy; most probably don't know that if you use the non-short circuiting `&` instead of `&&` you would get undefined behavior because of the unsequenced data race. Better to be explicit about that sort of thing.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I'm sorry, but banning boolean logic? Not with me. Also, much code, even side-effect-free code, depends on short-circuiting. Knowing the basics of the language one uses is necessary if one wants to get anywhere beyond copying "hello world"-programs.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Why would anyone switch to bitwise AND there?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Sometimes people use the `&` operator on boolean values in a conditional to deliberately avoid the short-circuiting behavior, because it can be faster in some cases than a branch. @ Dedup, It's not about banning boolean logic, it's trying to separate the part of the code where `answer` is not known to be valid from the part where it is. The fact that `validate_answer` is not called unless `err = 0` is essential here, so it makes sense to handle that completely before you start talking about `answer` as if it were valid.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro That sort of micro-optimisation is a poor way to code. A bitwise & in a conditional looks like a typo. If you're concerned about short-circuiting, refactor your code flow to avoid it. Use bitwise & for..... bitwise operations!

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I'm not endorsing the practice, but it does exist. As for "looks like a typo", well (1) that depends entirely on what you are habitually exposed to and (2) it very well may be a typo, and as pointed out a pretty bad one in this case. The combination of control flow and mutation in a single statement makes the code very tricky and literally one character away from UB. It smells very much like "clever" code. As for "refactor your code flow"... I did. That's literally the point of my original comment.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro So you did :)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Most code is literally one character away from undefined behavior.

Comment: @BenVoigt That sounds like an interesting code golf challenge: find a C++ program with hamming distance 1 to the most number of UB programs. :)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: let the number of "neighboring" UB programs be K and the length of the program be N, then maximize K / pow(N, 1 + a)... otherwise you can take any "fragile" sequence and just duplicate it in a new scope an arbitrary number of times to increase K arbitrarily.  Also I think you want to use Levenshtein (edit distance) not Hamming distance, as the initial example here involved a deletion `&&` -> `&` not a substitution

Comment: @BenVoigt: Nearly all non-contrived non-trivial C programs would be zero characters away from UB given a sufficiently obtuse reading of the Standard.

Answer (score 6):

It's valid but problematic for debugging, performance and reading clarity.

Can you use

```
void updateState() {

    // do some stuff before

    while (this.timeReference.isAfter(lastInterval.getBeggining()) 
    {
        this.timeReference = lastInterval.getEnd();
        lastInterval = intervalIterator.next();
    }

    // do more stuff after

}
```

instead if `maybeUpdateTime()` is only called by `updateState()`? If it's called by other functions, the condition in `while` could be wrapped to `maybeUpdateTime()` and inside the loop it is wrapped to `updateTime()`.

Or if you have performance requirements and don't want to (1) consume more CPU resources,  (2) block other tasks in the same thread, maybe consider put `maybeUpdateTime()` into a separate thread that allows you to wait for a task to complete (update time).

Comment: The problem with this approach is that, as I mentioned, `maybeUpdateTime` could be called outside `updateState`, any number of times. So it should be wrapped in its own function (for instance, it could be a way more complex computation, the code above is just an example).

Comment: @LucasNoetzold Can you rename `maybeUpdateTime` so that it communicates succinctly what is the stopping criteria for the `while` loop? This is not an answer in itself, but a better name can illuminate a way toward a better answer.

Comment: Its a good advice @rwong, but I'll not edit the question because it already have answers mentioning the names I gave.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, this doesn't communicate the intent very well and one might need to think for a few seconds to understand the logic.

If you have to keep the `maybeUpdateTime()` method as is, I would convert the loop into something like the following:

```
boolean needsUpdate = false;
do {
    needsUpdate = maybeUpdateTime();
}
while (needsUpdate);
```

This communicates the intent perfectly, doesn't require modifying the `maybeUpdateTime()` method, and doesn't force you to repeat some of the method's internal logic when calling it.

If you prefer a `while` loop, this can be written as:

```
boolean needsUpdate = maybeUpdateTime();
while (needsUpdate) {
    needsUpdate = maybeUpdateTime();
}
```

Comment: This is close to the answer I was going to write. A named variable adds a lot of readability here.

Answer (score 5):

### Empty while loops

An *empty* while loop is a bad idea.

At the very least, the loop should contain some waiting logic so you don't just blast through iterations. Something as simple as this:

```cs
while (thingIsStillRunning()) 
{ 
    await Task.Delay(250); 
}
```

This isn't the *best* approach but it is an acceptable one (in the right scenario). This ensures that you only perform the check at a reasonable interval.

Note that the precise length of that interval is up to you to decide. The bigger you make the interval, the more efficient it will be, but it will of course take longer to notice that the job has been completed. This is a matter of weighing performance vs response time.

Definitely consider working asynchronously here, as it frees up the thread during the wait.

---

### Intervals

It also seems like you might be reinventing the wheel here. Intervals are a well established concept and the .NET library already has a solution for them. From [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.interval?view=net-5.0):

```cs
using System;
using System.Timers;

public class Example
{
    private static Timer aTimer;

    public static void Main()
{
        // Create a timer and set a two second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Interval = 2000; // every 2 seconds

        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;

        // Have the timer fire repeated events (true is the default)
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;

        // Start the timer
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program at any time... ");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
    }
}
```

The example displays output like the following:

> The Elapsed event was raised at 5/20/2015 8:48:58 PM
> The Elapsed event was raised at 5/20/2015 8:49:00 PM
> The Elapsed event was raised at 5/20/2015 8:49:02 PM
> The Elapsed event was raised at 5/20/2015 8:49:04 PM
> The Elapsed event was raised at 5/20/2015 8:49:06 PM

If your interval is fixed, then this is a much more preferred approach. Even if your intervals are dynamically adjustable, it's still worth looking into manually resetting your interval timer (and reconfiguring the interval time as needed).

---

### "Maybe" logic

As an aside, `maybeUpdateTime` is not a good way to structure your methods. Your methods shouldn't leave the reader guessing as to what is or isn't happening. Instead, your methods should simply *do* the work, and then the "maybe" part should shown explicitly instead of hidden inside the method.

Compare these two examples:

```
maybeUpdateTime();
```

versus

```
if(timeNeedsUpdating())
    updateTime();
```

The second example makes it clear exactly when the time will or won't be updated. The reader doesn't event need to look inside either method to know what's happening. In the first example, you'd need to dig deeper before you'd understand what is happening.

Comment: "At the very least, the loop should contain some waiting logic so you don't just blast through iterations. Something as simple as this: `await Task.Delay(250);`" <- this is actually really dumb. The computer has a bunch of jobs to process, and there's absolutely no reason to delay 250ms after each job. Wouldn't you prefer if the jobs were processed as quickly as possible?

Comment: @user253751: Your comment doesn't make sense when the completion condition (i.e. breaking the loop) is not contingent on the number of iterations you've done. The loop is awaiting an external element (in this case the current time, but it could be any outside job), that job is always going to take exactly as long regardless of how quickly you iterate. In other words, it's going to take exactly as long from now until midnight, regardless of how often you check your watch. Checking your watch constantly and without delay does not make midnight come faster - but it does demand constant attention.

Comment: You also seem to misunderstand asynchronicity, as delaying one thread (as opposed to synchronously sleeping it) specifically does not block other threads (i.e. the "bunch of jobs" you're talking about).

Comment: The word "interval" in my example actually comes from intervals in production time of an industry, I didn't realize it could be interpreted as a sign of a busy loop at the time, if there weren't so many answers already I would think of a better example and edit it. But that method is an actual computation, not a busy loop.

Comment: @Flater Nothing in the question references the current time. I suggest you read it again. It is processing a queue of items which include timestamps. For some reason you have decided to insert a delay after processing item in the queue.

Answer (score 4):

I think the question is good but the example is bad.  In the example, `updateState` should advance the iterator in a single operation to the interval including the `timeReference`.  It should not iterate.

A better example might be running jobs from a queue, with methods `runOneJob()` and `runAllJobs()`.  I would have no qualms writing:

```
public void runAllJobs()
{
    while (runOneJob());
}
```

In light of some other answers, I might now write:

```
public void runAllJobs()
{
    while (runOneJob()) {}
}
```